# Docker for Windows: cannot assign requested address

Tags: windows, networking, docker

How can I setup a multi-host running Docker 1.12 on Hyper-V?

I can easily assign a 127.x.x.x ip, but I would like to assign e.g. 10.240.0.x.

This is my docker-compose.yaml:

```
version: '2'
services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:lastest
    ports:
      - "127.0.0.100:80:80"
```

If I try to assign 10.240.0.100 I get this error:
*Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp 10.240.0.100:80: bind: cannot assign requested address*

What am I missing? Do I have to configure Windows to support these addresses?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this using Docker for Windows? With that, you're limited to binding stuff to `localhost` on the host.

If you want to test a multi-node swarm on your machine, you need to set up a separate set of VMs:

```
> docker-machine create -d hyperv --hyperv-virtual-switch "Better New Virtual Switch" master
> docker-machine create -d hyperv --hyperv-virtual-switch "Better New Virtual Switch" worker1
> docker-machine create -d hyperv --hyperv-virtual-switch "Better New Virtual Switch" worker2
```

Init swarm:

```
> docker-machine inspect --format '{{ json .Driver.IPAddress }}' master
"192.168.202.112"
> docker-machine ssh master docker swarm init --advertise-addr 192.168.202.112
To add a worker to this swarm, run the following command:

    docker swarm join \
    --token SWMTKN-1-4k5ljcmxs1d9q14lth4tfbg868lf8eqi5alxtvgo7s1ptyrhlu-3ihz3bfmx5622vei1smzetudf \
    192.168.202.112:2377
```

Add the workers:

```
> docker-machine ssh worker1 docker swarm join --token SWMTKN-1-4k5ljcmxs1d9q14lth4tfbg868lf8eqi5alxtvgo7s1ptyrhlu-3ihz3bfmx5622vei1smzetudf 192.168.202.112:2377
> docker-machine ssh worker2 docker swarm join --token SWMTKN-1-4k5ljcmxs1d9q14lth4tfbg868lf8eqi5alxtvgo7s1ptyrhlu-3ihz3bfmx5622vei1smzetudf 192.168.202.112:2377
```

SSH into the master and go to town (or use it from the host):

```
> docker-machine ssh master
> docker node ls
 ID                           HOSTNAME  STATUS  AVAILABILITY  MANAGER STATUS
 aojoo2h0uuj5hv1c9xajo67o2    worker1   Ready   Active
 eqt1yd8x52gph3axjkz8lxl1z *  master    Ready   Active        Leader
```

Details here: https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/67#issuecomment-242239997

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but unfortunately I have some issues. _docker-machine ssh master_ returns this error: "dial tcp: too many colons in address fe80::215:5dff:fe63:102:22"

All machines also shows this error using _docker-machine ls_:
Unable to query docker version: Get https://[fe80::215:5dff:fe63:102]:2376/v1.15/version: x509: certificate is valid for 127.0.0.1, not fe80::215:5dff:fe63:102

I guess this might be related to [link](https://github.com/docker/machine/issues/3593)

Can I force the docker machine to use a IPv4 instead of IPv6?

Comment: @MartinSkovvangPetersen are you sure you specified a working switch with `--hyperv-virtual-switch` (you may have to create a new one, bridge to a network interface). I had this problem too, and it was because I used the default

Comment: I forgot to bridge the virtual switch to a network interface - that fixed the issue. The swarm solution works but also seems like a bit overkilled. I guess there is no other solution right now. Thank you for your help. I appreciate it.

Comment: @MartinSkovvangPetersen what would you prefer? If you just need to test swarm-mode features, you can do that on a single node using Docker for Windows out of the box. Just run `docker swarm init` - no docker-machine required

Comment: Basically I just need two containers running om same host port, which is why I need to map multiple host IPs. I have successfully mapped two containers as `-p 127.0.0.1:80:80` and `-p 127.0.0.2:80:80` and linked these. However it would be nice if I could choose another IP like 10.240.x.x instead of 127.x.x.x, but that's when I get the _cannot assign requested address_ error. I guess that this might be more related to a Windows question than Docker?